# tfs 2015 - Feature with status "done" with open bugs or PBI

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, tfs-process-template

I have a feature called Feature 1 with this hierarchy:

(I am using TFS 2015 update 2 with Scrum process template)

1. Feature1 (done)

   1.1. Bug 1 (Commited)

   1.2  PBI 1 (new)

It is kinda confusing how can I have a feature "Done" but with open bugs or PBIs.

Is there any way to control this (like moving the feature out of "done" status) or have a warning?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have a very valid ask but unfortunately this "feature" is not available today. Team Foundation Server does not auto-transition the parent/child work items.